# Does the absolute value even matter here?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In this problem I'm doing it says

> Suppose that $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed over the region {$(x,y):0\lt |y|\lt x\lt 1$}. Find the marginal densities $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$

Does the absolute value even matter here since it's all between $0$ and $1$ anyway? How is the answer $f_X(x)=2x$?

Comment: The absolute value definitely matters. It says the region includes, for example, $(2/3,-1/3)$, which it wouldn't do if the problem said $0\lt y\lt x\lt1$. For the main question, what do you know about computing marginal densities? How would you go about doing that?

Comment: Draw a sketch of the region in the $x$-$y$ plane over which $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed. If you think of the joint density as a (right triangular) prism sitting on the plane, then $f_X(x)$ is the _area_ of the cross-section of the prism at $x$. (hint: cross-section is a rectangle of height $1$ and base length? that you can read of from the sketch that you probably will not bother to draw.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see what you mean, thats a good point, thank you for the clairification. I would evaluate this integral: $2\int_0^1 f(x,y) dy$ for the marginal distribution of $X$, and f(x,y)=1 anyway. Which now makes $f_X(x)=2x$ clear.

Comment: @Kyle ...and $2\int_0^1f(x,y)dy$ is _not_ what you need to evaluate to find $f_X(x)$, though in this instance, because of the symmetry it gives the right answer. You should evaluate $$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy = \int_{-x}^x 1\,\mathrm dx = 2x ~ \text{for}~0 < x < 1.$$

Comment: I upvoted the question.  Could the person who down-voted it explain why?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Ah yes that makes more sense, I questioned myself after I posted that, thank you. No I didn't draw the sketch but I **did** however visualize it :-).

Comment: I also meant to ask one more question about this. Say I'm supposed to find the expected value of $Y$, am I evaluating the integral from $0$ to $1$ or from $-1$ to $1$? I think it's $0$ to $1$ just because in the problem it says that everything is defined between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @Kyle ...and once again, brief consideration of the sketch that you did not bother to draw will reveal that $f_Y(y)$ is an even function of $Y$ and so $E[Y] = 0$ without it being necessary to integrate, or more sedately, that $f_Y(y)$ is nonzero for $y \in (-1,1)$ and so the integral must have limits $\pm 1$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate could you repost your answer in the "answer" section so I can accept it as the answer? Otherwise I'm not sure what to do since my accepted answer is in the comment's section.

Comment: @Kyle Done!${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the OP's request

As Gerry Myerson pointed out, the absolute value sign does matter, and as Michael Hardy's answer clarifies in more detail, the joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ has nonzero constant value $c$ on the region 
$$\{(x,y) \colon -x < y < x, 0 < x < 1\},$$
that is, on the interior of a right triangle with vertices $(0,1), (1,1), (1,-1)$.
As I suggested in my comments on the question, sketching the $x$-$y$ plane 
and marking this triangle on it is very helpful as an aid 
to thought, and in this particular problem, makes the computations
very simple.  In fact, it is even better
if one can visualize the joint density as a solid sitting on the $x$-$y$
plane whose volume must necessarily equal $1$. In this instance, the solid
is a right triangular prism of height $c$, and since the triangular base
has area $1$, the height $c$ must also equal $1$.

For any fixed $x$, the  marginal density $f_X(x)$ is given by
$$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$$
which is, of course, the *area* of the cross-section of the
of the joint density solid if we were to slice the solid by
a plane parallel to the $y$-$z$ plane and at distance
$x$ from the $y$-$z$ plane. For $0 < x < 1$, the cross-section
is a rectangle of height $1$ and base extending from $y=-x$
to $y = x$, and so the area is $2x$. For $x\leq 0$ or $x \geq 1$,
the cross-section is $0$.  Thus we get
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}2x, &0 < x < 1,\\
0, &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
A similar calculation can be done to obtain the
marginal density $f_Y(y)$.  Now, for $0 \leq y < 1$,
the cross-section has base extending from $x = y$ to $1$,
and hence the area is $1-y$, while for $-1 < y \leq 0$,
the cross-section has base extending from $x = -y$ to $1$,
and hence the area is $1+y$. Thus, we have
$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}1-y, &0 \leq y < 1,\\
1+y, &-1 < y < 0,\\
0, &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
As a check on one's work, it is easy to sketch the density
functions and verify that they are nonnegative functions
and the "area under the curve" is $1$, that is, we have
found valid density functions and thus have not made any 
glaringly obvious errors in computation.

Finally, to compute $E[Y]$, one can of course use the
standard formula
$$E[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy
= \int_{-1}^0 y(1+y)\,\mathrm dy 
+ \int_{0}^1 y(1-y)\,\mathrm dy$$
and work out that $E[Y]=0$, but it is also possible to
avoid integration at all by considering that since
$f_Y(y)$ is an *even* function, the integral 
of the *odd* function $yf_Y(y)$ over the finite interval 
$(-1,1)$ must necessarily be $0$.  But be sure to remember
that this argument must be used with care if the integral
is over the entire real line.  See, for example,
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/239949/15941)
and its answers.

Answer (score 1):

$$
0<|y|<x<1
$$
is the same as
$$
0<x<1\text{ and for each value of $x$, }-x<y<x.
$$
The absolute value is redundant in the inequality $0<|y|$ (we don't care whether it's "$<$" or "$\le$" since the probability of being exactly equal is $0$ either way).  But the absolute value matters in the inequality $|y|<x$, and the "$0<$" is there in order to tell us that $0<x$.

As for your question about the marginal density: Let $f_X$ and $F_X$ be respectively the marginal density and the marginal cumulative distribution function.  Then
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \Pr(X\le x) = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\text{area of one triangle}}{\text{area of another triangle}}.
$$
Draw the two triangles and you'll see it.